Unable to see some fields to add in related list view
I'm trying to add some fields to a related list on Account and I'm not able to see OwnerId field under the list of available fields. I have this field on the object but it is not available in the list to add it to the list view. Any way to add this field on the list view?


I found a solution myself by creating a new formula field to include the Owner detail and it worked. I'm able to see this new field in the available section and able to add it to the list view.
